# tecdoc query take more than 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, sql, localhost

I have the tecdoc db, and I want to make a simple query for getting all the articles from a category for a type of engine, this query will be the most executed, but it takes more than 5 minutes, I am using mysql with InnoDB engine:

```
SELECT
    LA_ART_ID
FROM
               TOF_LINK_GA_STR
    INNER JOIN TOF_LINK_LA_TYP ON LAT_TYP_ID = $engine AND
                              LAT_GA_ID = LGS_GA_ID
    INNER JOIN TOF_LINK_ART ON LA_ID = LAT_LA_ID
WHERE
    LGS_STR_ID <=> $category
ORDER BY
    LA_ART_ID

 $engine = engine code;
 $category = category id;
```

I made index on LAT_TYP_ID, LAT_GA_ID, LAT_TYP_ID+LAT_GA_ID, LA_ID, LGS_STR_ID, but no success, the table has more than 150 mil entries. What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Saying that this is "the tecdoc db" without further details limits this question to users that are familiar with the tecdoc db (which, as you did not get a response, seems not to be enough to get an answer). To widen the pool, you should add: the structure of your tables (which of these columns belong to which table), the explain output (use `explain select LA_ART_ID ...`), how many rows are in each table (which table has 150 mill rows, how many for the others), and how many results you get from your query (how many items are in a category, how many belong to an engine, how many for both).

Comment: Hi, could you please tell me, where did you find MySQL TecDoc database? I'm searching for PHP parser, because i have data only in text files, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i changed some settings in my.ini

```
innodb_read_io_threads=2
innodb_write_io_threads=4
innodb_log_file_size = 512M
innodb_log_buffer_size = 8M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 1
innodb_lock_wait_timeout = 50
innodb_flush_method=O_DIRECT
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0
skip-innodb_doublewrite
```

and with explain feature i reduced the time from minutes, to secundes with right indexes.